# Generate EDI 856 in c#

Tags: c#, edi, edi.net

I am new to EDI, I have a task to generate an ASN file in EDI 856 format in c#. Can anybody please help me. I found [edi.net](https://github.com/indice-co/EDI.Net) on net but unable to figure out the POCO class for 856 format

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically, all EDI files have the same POCO structure. `Loop` - `Segment` - `Element` - `SubElement`

Comment: Just did this exact project. Originally it was in C# using XML, with XSLT and XSD templates. I scrapped it all and switched to SSIS. WAY EASIER

Comment: Agreed. Use the right tool for the job. It is much easier to export XML and do the conversation in an interface engine. Mirth Connect (from NextGen) is free and would be easy for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There is no transmission model ready to use but you can checkout the samples in the tests project in the repository in order to make one yourself.
Checkout this example https://github.com/indice-co/EDI.Net/blob/master/test/indice.Edi.Tests/Models/X12_850.cs which will get you started.

I suggest you clone the source code and play around with the samples.